# Same image across multiple sections and slides fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using Fullpage.js in my site and would like to use one image for the background for the whole site, where different parts of the image are displayed as different sections and slides are scrolled. So far I have managed to get different parts of the image showing for sections by adding:

```
<div class="fullpage">
```

at the top of the body with corresponding CSS:

```
.fullpage {
    background-image: url(../images/background_image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Is there any way to get the image to move sideways as slides are displayed.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbtga4L3/) of what I've got so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I decided to go a different route and convert the image into tiles. The image tiles are then assigned to the correct slide or section. This allows the image to continue from each slide or section without having to load the whole image at once.

Answer (score -1):

Yep! You'll need to hook into that slider gallery's events.

What plugin are you using? Or did you write it yourself?

Either way, most plugin slide galleries have events like "onSlideStart" or things like that, which you can then use to update your background.

I'd start by writing a script, and setting onSlideStart to a function that calculates what slide the slider is on. Then you simply set your background position (or rather, animate it) to the proper x-value based on what slide you're on (you can figure out the math yourself, yeah?)

Hope this helps!  :)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Me askng for clarification on what the OP using is asking too many questions? Sorry, but that's not a good reason for a downvote, since I actually *answered* the question. Please rethink your comment and voting practices. I never said the question was not clear, and I answered it well.